# Javascript: How to log out when the browser closes and not just a single tab?

Tags: javascript, browser, authentication, tabs, logout

I'm working on a website where I use javascript. Currently I'm making my own log in system. Now when I'm logged in I store the necessary information in session storage (don't worry it's a secure way). This however means that if I open a new tab and enters my page I'm not logged in, which I would like to be, since I'm already logged in, in another tab.

I was thinking of storing the information in local storage instead. But then if the browser is closed and reopened the user is still logged in. Now I could use onUnload or onBeforeUnload to log out. But then if the user is logged in, in two tabs and closes one of them, the user will also be logged out in the other.

So my question is: is there a way to detect if the user is have closed the entire browser and not just a tab or is there another way of solving this problem?

If possible I would like to avoid cookies.

Thank you in advance :)